# How can send the classes with the same category id to javascript and javascript send the results to another id and class?

Tags: javascript

1.I Want send the id name categ_1 and categ_2 in the example below id cat_no_1 and cat_no_2

2.I Want send the class with the same id of categ_1 and categ_2 in the example below class cat_no_1 and cat_no_2

```
<div class="categ" style="display:none;">

 <div class="the_categories" id="categ_1">Colors 1</div>
    <span class="categ_1">Blue</span>
    <span class="categ_1">Red</span>
    <span class="categ_1">Green</span>

 <div class="the_categories" id="categ_2">Colors 2</div>
    <span class="categ_2">Yellow</span>
    <span class="categ_2">Grey</span>
    <span class="categ_2">White</span>

</div>                                         

For example results on site:

<div class="button">
<a class="button dropdown" id="cat_no_1">Colors 1</a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu hold-on-click dropdown-checkboxes">
       <label class="cat_no_1">Blue</label>
       <label class="cat_no_1">Red</label>
       <label class="cat_no_1">Green</label>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
<a class="button dropdown" id="cat_no_2">Colors 2</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu hold-on-click dropdown-checkboxes">
      <label class="cat_no_2">Yellow</label>
      <label class="cat_no_2">Grey</label>
      <label class="cat_no_2">White</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: I Dont have tried because i dont now what javascript need to use you now some solution?